# Opencv giving access denied error in runtime

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am new in Opencv .In the android application, opencv works but in the logcat its giving error. How can I solve this problem ? In the runtime camera is running but further application I cannot do object recognition. What should I do? 
Any resource or documentation helps. Thank you.

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
```

Here my source code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements  CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{


    private static final String TAG = "OpenCV Taha Camera : ";
    public static CameraBridgeViewBase cameraBridgeViewBase;
    public TextView screen_info;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 100;


    static {

        if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV NOT LOADED.");
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV Loaded Successfully.");
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        screen_info = findViewById(R.id.screen_info);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},REQUEST_PERMISSION);
        }
        cameraBridgeViewBase = findViewById(R.id.camera_screen);
        cameraBridgeViewBase.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        cameraBridgeViewBase.setCvCameraViewListener(this);



        screen_info.setText("---No Info Currently---");

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV Library NOT LOADED! ");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_4_0,this,baseLoaderCallback);
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV Loaded Successfully");
            baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    private BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status){
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    cameraBridgeViewBase.enableView();
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }
}
```

Logcat :

```
> 05-03 00:20:22.550 789-789/? E/libc: Access denied finding property
> "persist.camera.debug.assert"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.debug.logfile" 05-03 00:20:22.550 789-789/? W/libc: Unable to set property
> "persist.camera.debug.logfile" to "0": connection failed; errno=13
> (Permission denied) 05-03 00:20:22.550 789-789/? E/libc: Access denied
> finding property "persist.camera.fdleak.enable" 05-03 00:20:22.551
> 789-789/? E/libc: Access denied finding property
> "persist.camera.global.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.mct.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.sensor.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.iface.logs"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.isp.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.pproc.debug.mask"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.imglib.logs" 05-03 00:20:22.552 789-789/? E/libc: Access denied finding property
> "persist.camera.cpp.debug.mask"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.hal.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.mmstill.logs"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.c2d.debug.mask"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.stats.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.stats.af.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.stats.aec.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.stats.awb.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.stats.asd.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.stats.afd.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.stats.q3a.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.stats.is.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.stats.haf.debug"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.stats.cafscan"
>     Access denied finding property "persist.camera.shim.debug"
```

Comment: Which android version is this running on?

Comment: Physical Android device Android 8.0.0